# Is the sentence "COVID-19 is an emerging, rapidly evolving situation" illogical?

Tags: word-usage

[National Institute of Health](https://www.nih.gov/health-information/coronavirus) (NIH) says

> COVID-19 is an emerging, rapidly evolving situation.

Obvious it makes sense. But is it a bit illogical?

"situation" might mean

> 1. a. The combination of circumstances at a given moment; a state of affairs. See Synonyms at state. b. A critical, problematic, or
>      striking set of circumstances: We don't want this minor gaffe to turn
>      into a situation.
> 2. The way in which something is positioned vis-à-vis its surroundings: the town's situation on the river.
> 3. Position or status with regard to conditions and circumstances: Their family's situation deteriorated during the recession.
> 4. A position of employment; a post: found a nice situation with a software company.

However, COVID-19 is a virus or a kind of virus, is it a bit illogical to call a virus a situation? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better put as "The COVID-19 pandemic."

Comment: This is a figure of speech, rather than something intrinsic to English. As such, it exists in other languages as well (most likely your first language as well!). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy

Comment: @userr2684291 your comment (with maybe a little fleshing out) would have made a good answer.  Care to post it as an answer instead? (I'll upvote it if you do)

Comment: For clarification, COVID-19 is not a virus.  COVID-19 is the name of the *disease* caused by the virus.  The name of the virus itself is actually SARS-CoV-2 (this is a common misunderstanding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> COVID-19 is an emerging, rapidly evolving situation.

In this case *COVID-19* doesn't refer to the disease, or the virus; it instead refers to the COVID-19 pandemic, caused by the virus.

The author of the sentence is employing a device called metonymy, whereby a part of something can be used to refer to the whole, or vice versa, as in *The school refused to comment on the issue*, where *the school* (the whole) refers to the representatives of the school (a part).

For more information about metonymy and synecdoche see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy.

While this is a common figure of speech, it's difficult to gauge when you should or shouldn't be using it.

As [a comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/243077/is-the-sentence-covid-19-is-an-emerging-rapidly-evolving-situation-illogical?noredirect=1#comment458460_243077) by user [Jack O'Flaherty](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/109772/jack-oflaherty) states, it might be better to write in full what is meant in this case, although it's unlikely that anyone would be unable to understand what is meant by *COVID-19* here, and make that tiny leap from *COVID-19* to *the COVID-19 pandemic*.